# What semantic notions underlie 頁 ('page') with '預' ('beforehand')?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

I'm especially baffled because 'page' is physical, but 'beforehand' isn't physical. I screenshot [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E9%A0%90)

[image]

and quote [預 - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A0%90#Chinese).

> [Phono-semantic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phonosemantic) compound (*[形聲](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BD%A2%E8%81%B2#Chinese)*, *OC *las*): phonetic *[予](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%88#Chinese)* (OC *la, *laʔ) + semantic *[頁](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A0%81#Chinese)*.
>
> #### Definitions
>
> 1. † [beforehand](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beforehand)
> 2. † to [take part](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_part) in
> 3. ([Xiamen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoy_dialect), [Zhangzhou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhangzhou_dialect) [Min Nan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min_Nan)) to [participate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/participate) in an [activity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/activity)
> 4. ([Xiamen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoy_dialect), [Zhangzhou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhangzhou_dialect), [Taiwanese Hokkien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwanese_Hokkien)) to [play](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/play) (chess, cards, mahjong, hide-and-seek, etc.)
> 5. ([Xiamen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoy_dialect), [Zhangzhou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhangzhou_dialect) [Min Nan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min_Nan), of an activity) to [start](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/start)
> 6. ([Cantonese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonese), [Teochew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teochew_dialect)) to [foresee](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foresee); to [expect](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expect); to [anticipate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anticipate)
>
>    - - [我](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%88%91#Chinese)**預**[咗](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%92%97#Chinese)[佢](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BD%A2#Chinese)[會](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%83#Chinese)[遲到](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%81%B2%E5%88%B0#Chinese)[㗎](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%97%8E#Chinese)[啦](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%95%A6#Chinese)。 [[Cantonese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonese), *[trad.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_Chinese)*]
>          [我](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%88%91#Chinese)**预**[咗](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%92%97#Chinese)[佢](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BD%A2#Chinese)[会](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BC%9A#Chinese)[迟到](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%BF%9F%E5%88%B0#Chinese)[㗎](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%97%8E#Chinese)[啦](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%95%A6#Chinese)。 [[Cantonese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonese), *[simp.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Chinese)*]
>
>      *Ngo5 **jyu6** zo2 keoi5 wui5 ci4 dou3 gaa3 laa1.* [Jyutping]
>
>      I **knew** he was going to be late.
>    - ([Cantonese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonese), [Teochew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teochew_dialect)) to [prepare](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prepare); to [plan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plan) for; to [estimate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/estimate)
>    - - [今晚](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BB%8A%E6%99%9A#Chinese)[有](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%89#Chinese)[朋友](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%8B%E5%8F%8B#Chinese)[上嚟](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8A%E5%9A%9F#Chinese)[食飯](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A3%9F%E9%A3%AF#Chinese)，[你](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BD%A0#Chinese)**預**[多](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A4%9A#Chinese)[啲](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%95%B2#Chinese)[飯餸](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%E9%A3%AF%E9%A4%B8&action=edit&redlink=1)[喇](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%96%87#Chinese)[喎](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%96%8E#Chinese)。 [[Cantonese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonese), *[trad.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_Chinese)*]
>          [今晚](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BB%8A%E6%99%9A#Chinese)[有](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%89#Chinese)[朋友](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%8B%E5%8F%8B#Chinese)[上嚟](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8A%E5%9A%9F#Chinese)[食饭](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A3%9F%E9%A5%AD#Chinese)，[你](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BD%A0#Chinese)**预**[多](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A4%9A#Chinese)[啲](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%95%B2#Chinese)[饭](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%E9%A5%AD%F0%A9%A0%8C&action=edit&redlink=1)[喇](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%96%87#Chinese)[㖞](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%96%9E#Chinese)。 [[Cantonese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonese), *[simp.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Chinese)*]
>
>      *Gam1 maan5-1 jau5 pang4 jau5 soeng6 lai4 sik6 faan6, nei5 **jyu6** do1 di1 faan6 sung3 laa3 wo3.* [Jyutping]
>
>      A friend is coming over for dinner tonight, so **prepare** more food.
>    - ([Cantonese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonese)) to [reserve](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reserve) a place; to [count someone in](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/count_in)

Comment: A general piece of advice: characters were composed a very long time ago, so the logic of characters comes from the meaning and sound of components' when the **character was first formed**, rather than what the character sounds like or means **now**.

Answer (score 3):

「預」 ([Zhengzhang OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Zhengzhang_(1981%E2%80%931995)): **/*las/**, *ahead/beforehand*) is comprised of semantic 「頁」 (*head*) and phonetic 「予」 (**/*laʔ/**).

---

The components of a character contribute hints to the character based on **what the components meant and/or sounded like at the time of the character's first appearance.** 「頁」 (**/*leb/**) did not originally mean *page*; that meaning is a [phonetic loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Rebus_(phonetic_loan)_characters) from 「葉」 (**/*leb/**, *leaf* > *flat sheet* > *page*).

「頁」 (*head*) was originally a picture of a [*kneeling person* 「卩」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=21830) drawn with an emphasised *head* 「」 ([now written 「首」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=1502)). The legs of the kneeling person 「卩」 was later replaced with the legs of  [「人」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=9).

> <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
> [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
> [image: 頁]
> [乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)8780
> [合集22217](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=22217&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
> [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
> [image: 頁]
> 卯簋蓋
> [集成4327](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4327&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
> [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
> [image: 頁]
> 法律答問75
> [睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd>
> <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
> [image: 頁]
> [頁部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77391&page=36)
> [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd><kbd>今
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image: 頁]</kbd>
>
> <sub>Forms 1, 2, 4, 5 refer to 「頁」. Form 3 refers to 「項」.</sub>

When it is found in other characters, 「頁」 holds the meaning *head* (anatomy from the shoulders upwards) as a semantic hint. For example,

- 頭 *head* (+ phonetic 豆)
- 頸 *neck* (+ phonetic 巠)
- 領 *neck* > *collar* (+ phonetic 令)
- 題 *head* > *main topic* (+ phonetic 是)
- 額 *forehead* (+ phonetic 客)
- 頂 *summit* (+ phonetic 丁)

Comment: What a coincidence! Old English leaf "leaf of a plant, foliage; page of a book, sheet of paper," You know what we say: Great minds think alike!

Answer (score 1):

*Outlier*

> **FORM**
>   預 yù is composed of 予 yǔ and 頁 “head,” which hints at the original meaning “in advance, ahead of time.” “Head” is also used to mean “earlier” in English, in words such as “ahead.” 予 gives the sound.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A0%81#Chinese)

> 頁 was later used as an alternative popular form of 葉 (“leaf; page”) to mean “sheet; page (of paper)”, which is its main meaning today.

So the part you're looking at changed its meaning in the intervening years.